# Local View with background images in2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

I am following a tutorial (the tutor using 2.79) I am using 2.8

He can go to local view without losing the reference images. I can not do that. I am aware that if I select them I can actually bring them to local view too, but I find it a little bit tedious.

Is it possible to make my background image/references always visible regardless if I jump in to local view or not?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there are no ways to do that.

I posted [a request on the Empty Images topic](https://developer.blender.org/T51366#646427), asking the devs to add an option for that.
Hopefully, this will be done, in which case I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: For the sake of completion, posted [here too](https://developer.blender.org/T52668#768220)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you select both the background image and the object you want to isolate, then hit back slash, both items can viewed

Comment: this was in Blender 2.8 RC 3

Answer (score -1):

Background images in Blender 2.8 can be viewed in both perspective and orthographic views.

You can add a background image by going to Add > Image > Background. Choose your image and no matter what view you're in, the image will appear.

Comment: local view is an isolation view mode, select an object and press numpad /. You'ill see in 2.8 it also isolates from background images.